# Connecting user input to a DOM's value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, button, forms

How can I connect a button which remains constant with a DOM's value in order to capture a user's selection?

I'm creating a taste questionnaire which asks users to select the style they prefer from amongst a series of pairs, and the specific pairings shown will change based upon the items previously selected. I'd like the 'Select' buttons under each set to remain constant so that the entire page doesn't need to be refreshed for each image.

**HTML**

```
<table>                          
<tr><td id="question" colspan=5 > Question 1</td></tr> 
<tr><td >
<img src="files/z1.png" name="taste" value="trendy[1]" />
</td> <td  >
<img src="files/z2.png" name="taste1" value="classic[1]"/>
</td> </tr> 
<tr><td >  
<img alt"Select" src="files/Select.jpg" onclick="javascript:manipulateDOM()"> 
</td><td  >
<img alt"Select" src="files/Select.jpg" onclick="javascript:manipulateDOM1()"> 
</td></tr></table>
```

**Javascript to determine which image is shown based on user input**

```
 var NumberOfImages = 7 - 1; //-1 because array members starts from 0
 var trendy = new Array(NumberOfImages);
 trendy[0] = "files/z1.png";
 trendy[1] = "files/z1.png";
 trendy[2] = "files/z14.png";
 trendy[3] = "files/z4.png";
 trendy[4] = "files/z5.png";
 trendy[5] = "files/z6.png";
 trendy[6] = "files/z9.png";
 var imgNumber = 1; //array key of current image
 var NumberOfImages = 7 - 1; //-1 because array members starts from 0
 var classic = new Array(NumberOfImages);
 classic[0] = "files/z2.png";
 classic[1] = "files/z2.png";
 classic[2] = "files/z12.png";
 classic[3] = "files/z3.png";
 classic[4] = "files/z3.png";
 classic[5] = "files/z7.png";
 classic[6] = "files/z8.png";
 var classicNumber = 1; //array key of current image
 var text = 6 - 1; //-1 because array members starts from 0
 var text = new Array;
 text[0] = "Question 1"
 text[1] = "Question 2"
 text[2] = "Question 3"
 text[3] = "Question 4"
 text[4] = "Question 5"
 text[5] = "Question 6"
 text[6] = "Question 7"
 var textNumber = 1; //array key of current image    
 function manipulateDOM() {
     changeObjects();
     NextImage();
 }
 function changeObjects() {
     document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = text[textNumber];
 }
 function NextImage() {
     if (imgNumber < NumberOfImages) //Stop moving forward when we are out of images
     {
         trendy[0] = trendy[1]; trendy[1] = trendy[2]; trendy[2] = trendy[3]; trendy[2] = trendy[3]; trendy[3] = trendy[4]; trendy[4] = trendy[5]; trendy[5] = trendy[6];
         document.images["taste"].src = trendy[imgNumber];
         classic[0] = classic[1]; classic[1] = classic[2]; classic[2] = classic[3]; classic[3] = classic[4]; classic[4] = classic[5]; classic[5] = classic[6];
         document.images["taste1"].src = classic[imgNumber];
         text[0] = text[1]; text[1] = text[2]; text[2] = text[3]; text[3] = text[4]; text[4] = text[5]; text[5] = text[6];
         document.getElementById["question"].innerHTML = text[textNumber];
     }
 }
 function manipulateDOM1() {
     changeObjects();
     NextImage1();
 }
 function NextImage1() {
     if (imgNumber < NumberOfImages) //Stop moving forward when we are out of images
     {
         trendy[0] = trendy[1]; trendy[1] = trendy[2]; trendy[2] = trendy[3]; trendy[2] = trendy[3]; trendy[3] = trendy[4]; trendy[4] = trendy[5]; trendy[5] = trendy[6];
         document.images["taste"].src = trendy[imgNumber];
         classic[0] = classic[1]; classic[1] = classic[2]; classic[2] = classic[3]; classic[3] = classic[4]; classic[4] = classic[5]; classic[5] = classic[6];
         document.images["taste1"].src = classic[imgNumber];
         text[0] = text[1]; text[1] = text[2]; text[2] = text[3]; text[3] = text[4]; text[4] = text[5]; text[5] = text[6];
         document.getElementById["question"].innerHTML = text[textNumber];
     }
 }
```

Comment: We are going to need some additional information in order to point you in the right direction. For example, what type of web server are you using?

Comment: @competent_tech - I agree to a degree, but what does the "type of web server" have to do with the approach?

Comment: @Jared Farrish: For example, if it is asp.net, then the OP may have set it up for auto-postback, which they don't want. Just trying to get a little context for the problem so we can figure out how to get the right info into the question.

Comment: @competent_tech - Ah, I see. Ajax can abstract that if the server needs to record/respond specifically, but I could see the client simply handling such a response. As you mention, more information would certainly be useful.

Comment: @competent_tech - I'm using a Linux server (via just.host.com), which isn't able to support asp.net.

Since I'm somewhat of a novice, I'd like to stick with html or javascript if at all possible.

Comment: I've started using some rudimentary PHP and JQuery, so suggestions in either one of those would be welcome too.

Comment: So you are trying to count hits on the two select images?